# JS ES6 class syntax and prototype confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

Okay, so according to my knowledge, we would write a class constructor like so

```
class User {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    //anything outside of constructor belong to this.prototype

    getName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
    getAge() {
        console.log(this.age);
    }
}
```

So instead, if I write something like this:

```
class User {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    getName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

User.prototype.getAge = function () {
    console.log(this.age);
};
```

It should technically be exactly the same, right? Or I am wrong? Because when I tried this which each one, I get 2 different result:

```
let user = new User('john', 23);

let properties = [];

for (let prop in user) {
    properties.push(prop);
}

console.log(properties); //The first code result : ["name", "age"]
                         //The second code result : ["name", "age", "getAge"]
```

So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: `class` defines the methods in it as non-enumerable, whereas assigning a new property directly to the prototype, creates an enumerable property (`for..in` iterates thorugh enumerable properties only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is that using `User.prototype.getAge = ...` will add the property with the property descriptor `enumerable: true`. This means it shows up in [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops.

> The `for...in` statement iterates over all [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)s), **including inherited enumerable properties**.

```js
class User {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    getName() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

User.prototype.getAge = function () {
    console.log(this.age);
};

let user = new User('john', 23);
let properties = [];

for (let prop in user) {
    properties.push(prop);
}

console.log(properties);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(User.prototype, "getName"));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(User.prototype, "getAge"));
```

If you want to define the prototype the exact same way you'll have to use the same property descriptor. This can be achieved with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
Object.defineProperty(User.prototype, "getAge", {
    value: function () {
        console.log(this.age);
    },
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The class syntax is only a sytactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are adding a property called `getAge`. And its type is function.